# Hardcoding values vs. reading from file

Tags: java, data-structures

This is a general question about the efficiency of hardcoding data - I'm writing a program in Java that does some chemical analysis, and I need to use the isotopic abundances of different elements. The way I have it set up right now is that all values (which never need to be modified) are stored as final fields in my class, i.e.

```
static final double C12Abundance = .989;
static final double C12Mass = 12;
```

A lot of similar programs store this type of data in an XML file, then read the values from there, like this:

```
<compounds>
<elements>
    <element symbol='C' mono_isotopic_mass ='12.00000000000' abundance='.989'/>
```

Is there any reason (performance, memory, etc) to read from it this way? Seems easier to just leave it as a field.

Comment: What if a new peer reviewed study shows that C12 is a bit more (or less) abundant?

Comment: @Ingo Most abundances are very well defined, if it did change most likely it would be a very small difference and in a specialized environment (i.e. not general atmospheric conditions). Plus I'm only hardcoding five different elements so I could always go back and update it.

Comment: Just saying, no offense. Another good reason to have them in a file is when you write your next program and need some more elements. And the next one. And so on. In that case, if you had that database and a class to read it at startup, you could just extend it, without disturbing the older programs or copying code from them.

Comment: No offense taken, thanks for the response. That's also a good point about reusability - at some point I might move it to an external file if I use those values in another program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard coding is way much faster in terms of performance and memory allocation.

The thing you gain from reading from a file is code re-usability (running your program with different parameters without the need to recompile it).

Note that reading from a file has the following steps:

1. Declare variable to use for storing a value.
2. Create an input (stream) object
3. Initialize it with a path
4. Open The file from FS
5. Find the correct line to read from
6. Read the value
7. Store it in the variable above
8. Close the input (stream)

That's a pretty big overhead instead of having a pre-compiled final variable with a value

Comment: The benefits is not very big if the value are only read once at the beginning of a big computation.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'll leave the data hard coded. In this particular case I can't imagine a scenario where I'd have to change these values (and even if I do I can just edit the source and recompile)

Answer (score 2):

As these are truely universal constants, properties limited in number, you can put them in code, but nicely organized.

```
public enum Element {
    //  Name Mass  Abund
    C12("C", 12.0, .989),
    He4(...),
    O32(...),
    ...;

    public final String name;
    public final double monoIsotopicMass;
    public final double abundancy;

    private Element(String name, double monoIsotopicMass, double abundancy) {
        this.name = name;
        this.monoIsotopicMass = monoIsotopicMass;
        this.abundancy = abundancy;
    }
}

for (Element elem : Element.values()) {
    if (elem.abundancy > 0.5) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hard-code the values and want to change them, you have to recompile your program, that's the problem. Reading your data from a file have the following benefits:

- You don't have to wait for the program to recompile for every change in the data. For a fairly large program, this can take time.
- Your users can change the data without even having access to the source.
- You can have different data sets between which you can switch just by changing the config file name.

Maybe none of this matter to you; then just go ahead and put your data in the source.

Performance itself (as in the performance of the program) is never a problem except if your profiler says so. But I don't see how reading for the data file at startup a small set of data could be a long process, so I'm fairly sure you would'nt see a difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you want so simulate a universe with a different abundance of C12, having the values hard coded would mean you have to recompile the program.

There may be other reasons as well: if the values are read from an external file the file serves as documentation, an external file may be easier to check for errors, there may be tools that generate the file or use it for other purposes besides running your program, ...

Answer (score 0):

A configuration file holds properties, generally speaking these properties are changing in time. I believe that in your case those are fixed and will never change, by definition.
For this reason I would do the easier thing possible, which is leaving them as fields.

This is not a performance matter, as long as performance doesn't show up being an issue, this is just a matter of what is more easily usable in your codebase.

I would advice you to extract these values in a class as constants, so you could always import it to access the values.

Answer (score 0):

The Java code in only readable by a Java compiler whereas XML is readable by any reasonable (meaning XML aware) language. Also If you want to add some value, you don't have to recompile everything.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd go for hardcoding if the values are not gonna be changed ever and if the app is small. Otherwise I would choose external sources of conf data.

But everytime people tell me that values are not gonna change, it pretty much means that they will so preparing dynamic environments is the way to go in general. XML conf files, database conf tables etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you write them in XML you can use different values for different devices,
e.g assume you have a dimension with name `item_margin` and it needs to be different based on width of device so in `values/dimens.xml` you have this

```
<dimen name="item_margin">0dp</dimen>
```

and in devices which has min **600dp** width you want this margin to be **60dp** so in
values-sw600dp/dimens.xml you have this

```
<dimen name="item_margin">60dp</dimen>
```

in this way these values are automatically selected based on device width, thus you don't have to check the device width and select appropriate value in your Java code